# How to ask the if statement in edit so that it recall the old data

Tags: codeigniter

this is the edit statement for edit users I would like to call the user data to edit it.  Yet I am receiving some strange result which I do not expect.

NAME    user2

EMAIL   user2@mail.com

ROLE    }">Administrator   manager

How to edit the code so that I get the right message - recalling the role as Administrator or manager it depends on the old data.

controllers/Cpages.php

```
public function editusers() { 

    $user_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $data['user'] = $this->Mpages->call_point_user($user_id);

    $this->load->view('editusers', $data); 

}
```

views/editusers.php

```
  <table border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 90px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>NAME</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $user_item->username; ?>"></td>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                            <td>EMAIL</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $user_item->email; ?>"></td>
                        </td>   
                        <tr>
                            <td>ROLE</td>
                            <td>
                            <select>
                            <optgroup>
                            <option value="<?if((echo $user_item->role;) == "administrator"){ echo "selected";?>}">Administrator</option>
                            <option value="<?if((echo $user_item->role;) == "manager"){ echo "selected";?>}">Manager</option>
                            </optgroup>
                            </select><?php echo $user_item->role; ?>
                            </td>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="edit" href="adminform.php">ADD</button></td>
                        </td>                           
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u get your data " $user_item->role " from your model? if no, i think you can try :

```
<?php echo $user['role']; ?> //to get data role that u send from controller
```

but if " $user_item->role " right, i think u just wrong when write if statement, try this :

```
<?php echo ($user_item->role == "administrator" ? "selected" : ""); ?>
```